# React native google maps street view

Tags: node.js, google-maps, react-native

is there an way to use google maps street view in react-native?

Looked at this library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-streetview) but this doesn't work with expo.

Any other options to use google street view in react native?

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @ChrisEdwards used WebView